# “System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed” when connecting to SFTP server with SSH.NET

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, sftp

Trying to upload file to SFTP server in my local. Hit error when connect SFTP.

I've tried using command-line and FileZilla to connect. It can connected.

```
 public static void UploadToSFTP(List<string> selectedFileList)
    {

            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(GeneralFunc.DBFile))
            {
                List<Model.SFTPSetting> sftpList = new List<Model.SFTPSetting>();
                string host = "myiphere";
                int port = 22;
                string username = "gth";
                string password = "1234";
                string dir = @"/D/SFTP";
                using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    client.ChangeDirectory(dir);
                    foreach (var file in selectedFileList)
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(testPath + "/" + file, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                            client.UploadFile(fs, Path.GetFileName(testPath + "/" + file));
                        }
                    }


                }

            }
        }
```

Unhandled Exception:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
01-09 16:28:12.248 E/mono    (18955): 
01-09 16:28:12.248 E/mono    (18955): Unhandled Exception:
01-09 16:28:12.248 E/mono    (18955): System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
01-09 16:28:12.248 E/mono    (18955):   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef (System.Boolean& success) [0x0001c] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
01-09 16:28:12.248 E/mono    (18955):   at System.Threading.NativeEventCalls.SetEvent (Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle handle) [0x00002] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
01-09 16:28:12.248 E/mono    (18955):   at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
01-09 16:28:12.248 E/mono    (18955):   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set()
```

Unhandled Exception:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket is not connected

01-09 16:28:17.309 E/mono-rt (18955): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
01-09 16:28:17.309 E/mono-rt (18955):   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef (System.Boolean& success) [0x0001c] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
01-09 16:28:17.309 E/mono-rt (18955):   at System.Threading.NativeEventCalls.SetEvent (Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle handle) [0x00002] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
01-09 16:28:17.309 E/mono-rt (18955):   at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the callstack is complete? I do not see any reference to your code in the callstack. + Does you code work in simple .NET console application? + Can you post [SSH.NET log](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/wiki/Troubleshooting-SSH.NET#net-tracesource-and-tracelisteners)?

Comment: hi martin..where i find the SSH.NET log ?

Comment: hi martin..my references like this..is correct ?

Comment: There's a link in my comment + I do not think that your problem has anything to do with references.

Comment: the code put in strings.xml ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin. In .NET it goes to `App.config`. - Though as I have suggested already, you better first test this locally in simple .NET console application.

Comment: not able to add app.config in xamarin android.